# Is it possible to add a cursor trail to web page and instead of a default trail it is a picture or a gif?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pointers, mouse

Something like the windows mouse trail.

[image]

Instead of the default pointer could there be a custom picture or gif
for a webpage in most likely javascript.

And how would I go about doing this, if its possible?

Edit: Thanks for some answers I tried

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/simpleimagetrail.shtm

And it for some reason made the 'trail' pretty far away from my mouse (disregard the dot trail)

https://i.gyazo.com/a03dd419dd4ca35e66e2b439c52e269d.mp4

Comment: yes, it is possible `And how would I go about doing this` - by learning javascript and writing code

Comment: This is a question about operating system ability / settings and as such is off topic here.

Comment: @marekful - no it isn't

Comment: @Jaromanda X, yes, this question in the form it was presented should be closed on SO, because it does not demonstrate a programming problem.

Comment: the cursor can be an image - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor - the trail is up to you

Comment: @marekful - it is a programming problem, javascript + css to do what is asked in the question, but I agree it's not a question that should be asked in its current state - it reads like a question from someone who hasn't done **any** research at all

Comment: Agreed. The "I want / need something, how is it possible" kind of questions are bad for SO in my opinion. The OP should edit the question to show their attempts to achieve the goal and summarise what they deduced from the research that was done _prior_ to asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for the Mouse Trail for my website.

```js
var dots = [],
    mouse = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };

var Dot = function() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.node = (function(){
    var n = document.createElement("div");
    n.className = "MouseTrail";
    document.body.appendChild(n);
    return n;
  }());
};

Dot.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.node.style.left = this.x + "px";
  this.node.style.top = this.y + "px";
};

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var d = new Dot();
  dots.push(d);
}


function draw() {

  var x = mouse.x,
      y = mouse.y;
      
  dots.forEach(function(dot, index, dots) {
    var nextDot = dots[index + 1] || dots[0];
    
    dot.x = x;
    dot.y = y;
    dot.draw();
    x += (nextDot.x - dot.x) * .6;
    y += (nextDot.y - dot.y) * .6;

  });
}

addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  mouse.x = event.pageX;
  mouse.y = event.pageY;
});

function animate() {
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
.MouseTrail {
    position: absolute;
    height: 7px; width: 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: teal;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect for me.
Only thing I had to change was to put some offset here in the draw function
var x = mouse.x + 2, 
y = mouse.y + 5; 

so I can click with no issues on links and buttons

Answer (score 0):

you should learn javascript.
here some example
[simple cursor image trail](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/simpleimagetrail.shtml)